# Identifying L shapes in an image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

How would i go about extracting the region of interest - which is the rectangle enclosed by the L shaped lines. Are there any functions in opencv or skimage that would help me with this? I am working with Python.

Note - The green boxes were drawn by me to highlight the ROI
[image]

Comment: Did you try something ? :)

Comment: @Arnaud I am a bit stuck actually. This is one of the exception cases from my original problem (99% of the time, the closed contours so i am able to solve it using findContours in openCV) , but for this particular case i don't know how to go around solving it

Comment: Huh? Which L-shaped lines? I see green boxes, a black `T` at bottom-left, a black inverted `T` at bottom-right and a bunch of odd, singleton lines.

Comment: Once I find the lines... do you mean you know where the lines are and you want to know how to cut the region of interest out and discard the other stuff? Or do you mean you don't know how to find the lines? Are the lines really on our images - or did you add them? ... wherever they are.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The Green boxes are drawn by me to highlight the region of interest. The ROI is what is obtained if you complete the L shaped line segments into a rectangle

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to know how to cut the ROI and discard everything else. This is actually an exception scenario in my original problem (which has bounded figures so extraction of ROI is easy)

Comment: [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html) would be the obvious place to start. Once you get a list of lines, you'll have to wade through them and figure out where the L's are

Comment: Do the lines have a predefined with? You might get a way with a couple of L shaped filters, like such `[[0, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 1], [0, -1, 0]]`. Convolve, find the peaks, grab the rest of the L.

Comment: Corner detection would be a way to go. Combined with a Hough transform.

Comment: @Eskapp  hey thanks the comment. Will definitely be looking into using corner detections. I was able to hack together a solution for now using contours .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by taking contours and drawing a min bounding rectangle around the contours.

There were still couple of exception cases to be handled such as - what if there are other contours whose min bounding rectangle overlaps the contours of the L shaped images , but for now i am happy with this result. Thanks for all the comments